# How to get pycassaShell working in windows?

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

EDIT: I got it working, I went into the pycassa directory and typed `python pycassaShell` but the 2nd part of my question (at the bottom there) is still valid: how do I run a script in pycassaShell?

I recently installed Cassandra and pycassa and followed the instruction from [here](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/tutorial.html#using-pycassashell).

They work fine, except I cant get pycassaShell to load. When I type `pycassaShell` at the command prompt, I get

```
'pycassaShell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Do I need to set up a path for it?

Also, does anyone know if you can run ddl scripts using pycassaShell? It is for this reason that I want to try it out. At the moment, I'm doing all my ddl in the cassandra CLI, I'd like to be able to put it in a script to automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to be running scripts with pycassaShell.  It's designed more as an interactive environment to quickly try things out.  For serious scripts, I recommend just writing a normal python script that imports pycassa and sets up the connection pool and column families itself; it should only be an extra 5 or so lines.

However, there is an (undocumented, I just noticed) optional `-f` or `--file` flag that you can use.  It will essentially run `execfile()` on that script after startup completes, so you can use the `SYSTEM_MANAGER` and `CF` variables that are already set up in your script.  This is intended primarily to be used as a prep script for your environment, similar to how you might use a .bashrc file (I don't know of a Windows equivalent).

Regarding DDL statements, I suggest you look at the [SystemManager](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/api/pycassa/system_manager.html) class.